# Why infinity is key to simplifying a Gauss's Law problem (for rod, and plane charges)?

Tags: gauss-law

Rod charge

[image]

Plane Charge side view

[image]

In both cases, the Gaussian surface (imaginary) is a cylinder, in order to simplify things. But what is more important is that two things are both infinite in dimension. The road is infinitely long. And the plane expands in every direction infinitely.

My book says. In the rod case, the infinitely long rod is 180 degree symmetric around any axis that is perpendicular to, and goes through it. And in the plane case, the infinitely big plane is 180 symmetric around any axis perpendicular to the plane.

Answer (score 1):

If the rod isn't infinitely long, there will be asymmetric behavior at the ends. In order to have a simple application of Gauss' Law, we use a cylinder and assume the rod is long enough to neglect end behavior. If the end behavior interfered, the field would not be all directly perpendicular to the cylinder, and the surface integral would become complicated. So, we assume infinite length to get around this problem (the length isn't really infinite, but just long enough such that the end behavior doesn't enter our calculation to a good approximation).

Comment: One strange thing with the plane charge is that field is equal to area charge density divided by (2 times permittivity constant). Why no distance?

Comment: @user132522 - well, it is one of those nice things that happens when you integrate out to infinity...

Comment: Its not intuitive. The great the distance from the plane, the less the field.

Comment: No, the flux is proportional to the area, the field is constant everywhere. It makes sense that the field is constant, because we assume spatial homogeneity.